# Data is not saving while excel sheet uploading using asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, excel

Data is not saved in database while uploading Excel sheet.

I am using ASP.NET and C# to upload an Excel sheet and save its data into the database. I am new to .net, I get help from https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0c1bb2/uploading-and-downloading-excel-files-from-database-using-as/ .

The file is uploaded successfully, mag is shown, but the data is not being saved in the database.

This is my code:

```
protected void Button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblMessage.Visible = true;

    string filePath = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName; // getting the file path of uploaded file  
    string filename1 = Path.GetFileName(filePath); // getting the file name of uploaded file  
    string ext = Path.GetExtension(filename1); // getting the file extension of uploaded file  
    string type = String.Empty;

    string CustomerID = String.Empty;
    string AddressType = String.Empty;
    string AddressLine1 = String.Empty;
    string AddressLine2 = String.Empty;
    string StateID = String.Empty;
    string DistrictID = String.Empty;
    string PinCode = String.Empty;
    string ResidencePhoneNo = String.Empty;
    string OfficePhoneNo = String.Empty;
    string Mobile = String.Empty;
    string EmailID = String.Empty;

    if (!FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        lblMessage.Text = "Please Select File"; //if file uploader has no file selected  
    }
    else if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        try
        {
            switch (ext) // this switch code validate the files which allow to upload only excel file you can change it for any file  
            {
                case ".xls":
                    type = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
                    break;

                case ".xlsx":
                    type = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
                    break;
            }

            if (type != String.Empty)
            {
                Stream fs = FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream;
                BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs); //reads the   binary files  
                Byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length); //counting the file length into bytes                               

                try
                {
                     SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Odisha_2May2019ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
                     conn.Open();

                     String query = "insert into CustomAddress( AddressType, CustomerID, AddressLine2, AddressLine1, PinCode, ResidencePhoneNo, " +
                            "OfficePhoneNo, Mobile, EmailID)" + "values ( @AddressType, @CustomerID, @AddressLine2, @AddressLine1, " +
                            " @PinCode, @ResidencePhoneNo, @OfficePhoneNo, @Mobile, @EmailID)";
                     query = "insert into CustomAddress(StateID, DistrictID) select s.StateID, d.DistrictID from State s, District d Where s.StateName=@StateID and d.DistName=@DistrictID";

                     SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
                     com.Parameters.Add("@CustomerID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = CustomerID;
                     com.Parameters.Add("@AddressType", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = "1";
                     com.Parameters.Add("@AddressLine2", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = AddressLine2;
                     com.Parameters.Add("@AddressLine1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = AddressLine1;
                     com.Parameters.Add("@StateID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = StateID;
                     com.Parameters.Add("@DistrictID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = DistrictID;
                     com.Parameters.Add("@PinCode", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = PinCode;
                     com.Parameters.Add("@ResidencePhoneNo", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = ResidencePhoneNo;
                     com.Parameters.Add("@OfficePhoneNo", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = OfficePhoneNo;
                     com.Parameters.Add("@Mobile", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = Mobile;
                     com.Parameters.Add("@EmailID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = EmailID;                                                     

                     com.ExecuteNonQuery();

                     lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                     lblMessage.Text = "File Uploaded Successfully";
                     conn.Close();
                 }
                 catch (Exception ex)
                 {
                     Response.Write("error" + ex.ToString());
                 }
             }
         }
    }
}
```

I just want to know, how to get data from the Excel sheet saved in the database. Or correct me where I'm wrong.

Comment: Hello, you forget to read the excel file

Comment: If i want to use this code, then how can i read the excel file.

Answer (score 0):

You can read data from excel with this method

```
  private DataTable GetTableFromExcel()
    {

        Workbook book = new Workbook();
        book.InvalidFormatException += book_InvalidFormatException;
        book.LoadDocument(FilePath);
        Worksheet sheet = book.Worksheets.ActiveWorksheet;
        Range range = sheet.GetUsedRange();
        DataTable table = sheet.CreateDataTable(range, false);
        DataTableExporter exporter = sheet.CreateDataTableExporter(range, table, false);
        exporter.CellValueConversionError += exporter_CellValueConversionError;
        exporter.Export();
        return table;
    }
```

And when you clik the button call the method

```
protected void Button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//your code
   else if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
{
  DataTable table = GetTableFromExcel();
  for (int i = 1; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
// your code 2
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another Method to read excel by Using System.Data.OleDb Namespace

```
    private static DataTable ReadExcelData(string FilePath)
    {
        string conStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0}; Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes'"; ;
        conStr = String.Format(conStr, FilePath);
        OleDbConnection connExcel = new OleDbConnection(conStr);
        OleDbCommand cmdExcel = new OleDbCommand();
        OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        cmdExcel.Connection = connExcel;

        //Get the name of First Sheet
        connExcel.Open();
        DataTable dtExcelSchema;
        dtExcelSchema = connExcel.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
        string SheetName = dtExcelSchema.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
        connExcel.Close();

        //Read Data from First Sheet
        connExcel.Open();
        cmdExcel.CommandText = "SELECT * From [" + SheetName + "]";
        oda.SelectCommand = cmdExcel;
        oda.Fill(dt);
        connExcel.Close();


        return dt;
    }
```

And on Button Click, you can call as Below

```
 protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {
            DataTable dt = ReadExcelData(@"your Excel Document Path");
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                //Your Code to insert record into the database
            }
        }
    }
```